# How to remove known portion from a text and get the arbitrary strings from it in js?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a text format like this:

> what is your favorite color from these?

Here color can be replaced with anything the user wants. For example food, juice, movie, book, etc.
Now I want to remove the `what is your favorite` and `from these?` parts and only want the part that the user has inputted.

I know I can do slice twice to get that. Is there any other elegant solution? like regex?

edit: I am actually making a bot, so I can't use template literals. I need the text as it is and disregard the known portion from it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know what you want to replace, simply match that with a regex and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: @PoulBak is it possible to match text with regex when there is some strings in the middle of what I want to remove?

Comment: `/what is your favorite|from these?/g` Note I use alternation and the global flag.

Comment: @Nithur I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your requirement/expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template literal syntax `` to do that.

Example:

> var color = document.getElementById('user-input'); // just for the
> idea
>
> `what is your favorite ${color} from these?`

And it will dynamically append the user input inside the string.

Comment: my use case is completely different. I am not developing a web app. Actually a bot, so I need to extract some specific portion and disregard the know portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
let defaultVal = 'color';
let str = `what is your favorite ${defaultVal} from these?`;

function getUpdatedVal() {
    const val = document.getElementById('val').value;
  if (val) {
    str = str.replace(defaultVal, val)
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = str;
  defaultVal = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val" onchange="getUpdatedVal()"/>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is one of the core mechanics in regular expressions. It allow you to get specific part of source text after matching. To solve your problem, you can use this pattern:

```
what is your favorite (\w+) from these\?
```

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OOrIp/1)

After matching is success, target word will be in first capturing group.